# Python не видит функцию (про области видимости)

Tags: python

**proga.py**:

```
import f1 as f1

def func():
    return 'func'

f1.f1()
```

**f1.py**:

```
def f1():
    func()
```

Не работает :(  Ошибка в f1.py: "func() is not definned".
Как из f1.py увидеть "func" ?

Comment: импортнуть:
from proga import func

Comment: У вас не выйдет это сделать из-за циклического импорта (который вы еще не сделали). Приведите полное задание для помощи.

Comment: Я понимаю, что "import" - не аналог инклуду.   Мне сам принцип понять - можно ли из импортнутого файла достучаться до вызывающего объекта?

Comment: Вы можете вызвать `f1()` из `proga` при наличии импорта в `proga` или вызвать `func` из `f1.py`. А сейчас вы пытаетесь перекрестить их, создавай циклический импорт (одно ссылается на другое).

Comment: Нельзя. К тому же смысл этого неясен.

Answer (score 1):

```
# f1.py
from proga import func
func()
```

Так делать нет смысла `import f1 as f1`, у вас и так имя `f1`.
Если в `proga.py` будет одноименная функция `func`, тогда импорт нужно делать с алиасом.

Ну и конечно не надо забывать о рекурсивном импорте, это когда вы из одного модуля импортируете что-то в другом, в котором в свою очередь импортируете что-то из первого. Таких вещей нужно избегать!

Comment: да я поправил, запутался в этих дебрях =)

Answer (score 1):

Для чего вам это нужно? Если f1 подразумевается как либа, это неправильная логика и так делать нельзя, классы и функции из либы не должны использовать какие-либо внешние функции и классы. Но эта либа может зависеть от других и можно сделать так:

**func.py**

```
def func():
    return 'func'
```

**f1.py**

```
from func import func
def f1():
    func()
```

Либо же можно передавать функцию **func** как аргумент для **f1**.

Comment: Да, я уже перестроил всё. Но в паре мест всё равно пришлось ref на внешнюю функцию в виде параметра передавать :)  Структура сложная, по другому не могу выкрутиться :)